# Equivalence relation on field extensions, explanation

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, extension-field, schemes

I am confused with [lemma 25.13.3](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01J5). Especially with the equivalence.

At -2 lines of lemma 25.13.3
, the author writes,

> Given any set of extensions $\kappa \subseteq K_i$ there exists some field extension of $\kappa \subseteq \Omega$ such that all the field extensions $K_i$ are contained in the extension $\Omega$.

Does this not imply that we have an $\Omega$ completing the diagram at -3 lines for any $K,L$?

Hence $p:Spec(K) \rightarrow X, q:Spec(L) \rightarrow X$  are equivalent for any choice of $K,L$ given that they have the same image? It seems to me that this equivalence is unnecessary...

Comment: I think that's the point, they want to classify points of $X$ so they have to identify a $K$- and an $L$-point whenever they have the same image.

Comment: Then why not just classify as you said - two morphisms $p,q$ equivalent from fields $Spec(K), Spec(L)$ iff they have same image?

Comment: That I can't tell you, honestly I have never seen this applied anywhere.